# ORM in Django vs. PHP Doctrine

Tags: php, python, django, orm, doctrine

I am a PHP guy. In PHP I mainly use Doctrine ORM to deal with database issues. I am considering move to Python + Django recently. I know Python but don't have experience with Django. Can anyone who has good knowledge of both Doctrine and ORM in Django give me a comparison of **features** of these two ORM implementations?

Comment: I was moving from Doctrine to Django recently and it was harmless. So you can go ahead.

Comment: @Tomasz - I don't care much about learning curve. Instead, I care about development efficiency. Does ORM in Djoango has as many cool features as Doctrine? For example, tree structure support out of box!

Comment: It's nearly impossible to compare Python and PHP.  Therefore, tools and frameworks built in these languages are almost impossible to compare.  They're different.  If they were similar enough to compare, there would be a compiler or translator.  Please list **specific** questions you have.  Code samples help us to understand the questions you have.

Comment: can't you just look it up in the docs or tutorial on djangoproject.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django ORM does everything I want it to do. I've found it to be easier to use and more straight-forward than Doctrine.  Sorry that I can't help with an in-depth comparison.

If you find the Django ORM is missing a feature you'd like to have, check out [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It can easily be used with Django.

Answer (score 5):

I am a rare person who had to switch from Django 1.4 to Symfony 2.1 so I had to use Doctrine 2 instead of current Django ORM.

Maybe Doctrine can do many things but let me tell you that it is a nightmare for me to use it coming from Django.

I'm bored with the verbosity of php/Symfony/Doctrine ...

Also I never needed something that Django's ORM didn't manage already (maybe projects not big enough to reach the limits).

Simply compare the description of data between both orms (including setters & getters)...

Answer (score 1):

Ive used Doctrine over a 2 year project that ended 1.5 years ago, since then i've been doing mostly Django.

I prefer Djangos ORM over Doctrine any day, more features, more consistency, faster and shinier.

Answer (score -1):

Django isn't just an orm. It is a web framework like symfony. The form framework in symfony is modeled on django for example. It's orm part is more like doctrine 2 I think, but I haven't played with either much.

Comment: I know Django is a framework, and it is probably the best framework of Python. Playing with DB is a very important issue in web development. And Doctrine is doing a good job for this. What I want to know is that, is the ORM implementation in Django as awesome as Doctrine?

Comment: _"Awesome"_ is not highly scientific.

Comment: Its not just as awesome. It easts doctrines lunch. The PHP object model places a number of restrictions on what an ORM can do compared to pythons Django and SQLAlchemy, mostly related to Pythons introspective capacities. I'm yet to find many use cases where I'm forced to revert to SQL, and I'm the kind of SQL guy that writes 2 pager SQL queries with an A-Z glossary of primatives required to understand what I'm doing. Its great stuff. And moreso Pythons terseness creates beautiful and instantly comprehendable models. You really can't go wrong.